# url not redirecting in chrome

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I put a 301 redirect code in htaccess. When I try to access the old url it redirects to new url without any problem in Firefox but in Chrome it is not redirecting.

Is it the problem with the htaccess code or some other problem.

I have cleared Chrome cache number of times but still no luck.

Final htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.herotscareers.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.webhelptsccareers.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^herotscareers.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.webhelptsccareers.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^.+$ /
```

www.herotscareers.co.uk or herotscareers.co.uk is redirecting to http://www.webhelptsccareers.com without any problem but http://www.webhelptsccareers.com/anyfolder/ is not redirecting to http://www.webhelptsccareers.com

Comment: If you could edit and show your .htaccess code we could help a bit more ;)

Comment: @all Updated my question with code and url.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 3 rules with this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.webhelptsccareers\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.webhelptsccareers.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: I cleared the cache but still it is not redirecting. I am updating my question with the last updates.

Comment: Question is not showing my suggested rule. You need to comment out all of your rules and keep only this one. Then clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: I did that and also cleared the cache but still it is not redirecting.Please try http://www.webhelptsccareers.com/working/

Comment: and after doing that http://www.herotscareers.co.uk/ is not redirecting to http://www.webhelptsccareers.com/

Comment: It wouldn't be ... it's just a rule to redirect all domains which don't start with `www` to `www`. Not at all what the question asks.

Comment: I have modified this answer, please retest.